# SIGABRT Crash when attaching a document to a PDFView

Tags: swift

I'm very new to Swift - having some trouble doing the simple task of displaying a document in a PDFView. I am not using Storyboards or IBOutlets etc. Any idea why the below is crashing?

I have tried referencing an external link, but it gives me the same error. The PDF exists in the bundle directory.

import UIKit
import PDFKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
private var pdfView = PDFView()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    let myNewView = PDFView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 100, width: 500, height: 500))

    // Add border to UIView
    myNewView.layer.borderWidth=2

    // Change UIView Border Color to Red
    myNewView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor

    guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "CV", ofType: "pdf") else { return }
    let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
    let document = PDFDocument(url: url)
    myNewView.document = document

    // Add UIView as a Subview
    self.view.addSubview(myNewView)
}
```

}

Build succeeds. But I get the below.

2019-06-13 17:49:35.702174+0100 Appp[81235:19343962] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'CALayerInvalidGeometry', reason: 'CALayer position contains NaN: [nan nan]'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001083446fb **exceptionPreprocess + 331
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000106250ac5 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000108344555 +[NSException raise:format:] + 197
    3   QuartzCore                          0x000000010b4072ae _ZN2CA5Layer12set_positionERKNS_4Vec2IdEEb + 140
    4   QuartzCore                          0x000000010b3f668b -[CALayer setPosition:] + 57
    5   QuartzCore                          0x000000010b3f6de3 -[CALayer setFrame:] + 560
    6   PDFKit                              0x0000000107135097 -[PDFPageLayerTile initWithFrame:forPageLayer:withRenderingTransform:tileContentsScale:generationID:] + 168
    7   PDFKit                              0x000000010713a805 -[PDFPageLayer _updateTiles] + 3439
    8   PDFKit                              0x0000000107135d8e -[PDFPageLayer setNeedsTilesUpdate] + 87
    9   PDFKit                              0x000000010714a97d -[PDFPageView setNeedsTilesUpdate] + 48
    10  PDFKit                              0x000000010714c816 -[PDFPageView setFrame:] + 334
    11  PDFKit                              0x000000010714311c -[PDFDocumentView createPageViewForPageAtIndex:] + 764
    12  PDFKit                              0x0000000107144326 -[PDFDocumentView updateVisibility] + 1726
    13  PDFKit                              0x00000001071b376f -[PDFView resizeDisplayView:] + 517
    14  PDFKit                              0x00000001071accdf -[PDFView layoutDocumentView] + 464
    15  PDFKit                              0x00000001071a836a -[PDFView setDocument:waitDuration:] + 1246
    16  Appp                             0x000000010596c4d1 $s7Appp14ViewControllerC11viewDidLoadyyF + 1441
    17  Appp                             0x000000010596c7b4 $s7Appp14ViewControllerC11viewDidLoadyyFTo + 36
    18  UIKitCore                           0x000000010d0ec43b -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 1183
    19  UIKitCore                           0x000000010d0ec868 -[UIViewController view] + 27
    20  UIKitCore                           0x000000010d724c33 -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 122
    21  UIKitCore                           0x000000010d725327 -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 289
    22  UIKitCore                           0x000000010d737f86 -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 42
    23  UIKitCore                           0x000000010d6e7f1c -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 4555
    24  UIKitCore                           0x000000010d6ed0c6 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1617
    25  UIKitCore                           0x000000010cf326d6 __111-[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability _scheduleFirstCommitForScene:transition:firstActivation:completion:]_block_invoke + 904
    26  UIKitCore                           0x000000010cf3afce +[_UICanvas _enqueuePostSettingUpdateTransactionBlock:] + 153
    27  UIKitCore                           0x000000010cf322ec -[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability _scheduleFirstCommitForScene:transition:firstActivation:completion:] + 236
    28  UIKitCore                           0x000000010cf32c48 -[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability activateEventsOnly:withContext:completion:] + 1091
    29  UIKitCore                           0x000000010cf30fba __82-[_UIApplicationCanvas _transitionLifecycleStateWithTransitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke + 782
    30  UIKitCore                           0x000000010cf30c71 -[_UIApplicationCanvas _transitionLifecycleStateWithTransitionContext:completion:] + 433
    31  UIKitCore                           0x000000010cf359b6 __125-[_UICanvasLifecycleSettingsDiffAction performActionsForCanvas:withUpdatedScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:]_block_invoke + 576
    32  UIKitCore                           0x000000010cf36610 _performActionsWithDelayForTransitionContext + 100
    33  UIKitCore                           0x000000010cf3571d -[_UICanvasLifecycleSettingsDiffAction performActionsForCanvas:withUpdatedScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:] + 223
    34  UIKitCore                           0x000000010cf3a6d0 -[_UICanvas scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:] + 392
    35  UIKitCore                           0x000000010d6eb9a8 -[UIApplication workspace:didCreateScene:withTransitionContext:completion:] + 514
    36  UIKitCore                           0x000000010d2a2dfa -[UIApplicationSceneClientAgent scene:didInitializeWithEvent:completion:] + 361
    37  FrontBoardServices                  0x00000001135df125 -[FBSSceneImpl _didCreateWithTransitionContext:completion:] + 448
    38  FrontBoardServices                  0x00000001135e8ed6 __56-[FBSWorkspace client:handleCreateScene:withCompletion:]_block_invoke_2 + 283
    39  FrontBoardServices                  0x00000001135e8700 __40-[FBSWorkspace _performDelegateCallOut:]_block_invoke + 53
    40  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001096d7db5 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    41  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001096db2ba _dispatch_block_invoke_direct + 300
    42  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000011361a146 __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK** + 30
    43  FrontBoardServices                  0x0000000113619dfe -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 451
    44  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000011361a393 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 42
    45  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001082abbe1 **CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION** + 17
    46  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001082ab463 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 243
    47  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001082a5b1f __CFRunLoopRun + 1231
    48  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001082a5302 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 626
    49  GraphicsServices                    0x00000001107c62fe GSEventRunModal + 65
    50  UIKitCore                           0x000000010d6eeba2 UIApplicationMain + 140
    51  Appp                             0x000000010596f68b main + 75
    52  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010974c541 start + 1
    53  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code. I wonder if maybe the PDF file is corrupt in some way? Perhaps try another PDF file just to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

If you move `myNewView.document = document` to `viewDidAppear:` instead of `viewDidLoad`, the document will load without issue.

Unfortunately, there were changes to iOS between 12.1 and 12.2 that make this necessary.